# Exception Filters MVC - Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am not getting logger instance in OnException method. I am using IunityContainer and have initialized in Global.asax

Please help me to correct the code.

Thanks

```
public class InjectIntoActionInvoker : ControllerActionInvoker
    {
        private IUnityContainer _container;

        public InjectIntoActionInvoker(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        protected override ActionExecutedContext InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(
            ControllerContext controllerContext,
            IList<IActionFilter> filters,
            ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
            IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
        {
            foreach (IActionFilter filter in filters)
            {
                _container.BuildUp(filter.GetType(), filter);
            }

            return base.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(controllerContext, filters, actionDescriptor, parameters);
        }

    }


private ILogger logger;

        [Dependency]
        public ILogger _logger
        {
            get
            { 
                return this.logger; 
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    this.logger = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext != null && filterContext.Exception!=null)
            {
                _logger.LogError(filterContext.Exception.Message, filterContext.Exception);
            }

        }

    }

public static class Bootstrapper
    {

        public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
        {
            var container = BuildUnityContainer();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
            return container;
        }

        private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            RegisterTypes(container);
            return container;
        }


        public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            container.RegisterInstance<ILogger>(new Logger());
            container.RegisterType<IActionInvoker, InjectIntoActionInvoker>();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try injecting the logger in constructor...

```
    public InjectIntoActionInvoker(IUnityContainer container, ILogger lo)
    {
        _container = container;
        this._logger = lo;
    }
```

Comment: I am getting the instance InjectIntoActionInvoker which is correct but not getting on OnException method. OnException method, I have written in different assembly code, is that the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not convinced this is going to work for you without using a controller factory. I'm stealing the code example from [here](https://gist.github.com/NOtherDev/3766954), but this gives you a good idea on how to create a customer controller factory, which also configures a custom action invoker:

```
public class MyControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext context, string controllerName)
    {
        var controller = base.CreateController(context, controllerName);
        return ReplaceActionInvoker(controller);
    }

    private IController ReplaceActionInvoker(IController controller)
    {
        var mvcController = controller as Controller;
        if (mvcController != null)
            mvcController.ActionInvoker = new ControllerActionInvokerWithDefaultJsonResult();
        return controller;
    }
}

public class ControllerActionInvokerWithDefaultJsonResult : ControllerActionInvoker
{
    public const string JsonContentType = "application/json";

    protected override ActionResult CreateActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, object actionReturnValue)
    {
        if (actionReturnValue == null)
            return new EmptyResult();

        return (actionReturnValue as ActionResult) ?? new ContentResult()
        {
            ContentType = JsonContentType,
            Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(actionReturnValue)
        };
    }
}
```

You could still have the custom action invoker, and controller factory for that matter, in a different assembly if you want.